# How to make a form input part of a website destination?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select form made in html and I want to make the selected value part of the url destination when they submit it. 
Example:

```
<form>
<select name="state" id="state">
              <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
              <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
              <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
              <option value="CA">California</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And when they choose, let's say "CA", I want the submit button go to "www.example.com/ca.html".

Here's my JS:

```
var stLocation = document.getElementById("state").value;
  window.location.href = 'www.example.com/stLocation.html';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to include your**jQuery library** to your script. Then you try this

```
$('button').click(function (){
    selectedValue = $('select').val().toLowerCase(); //I converted it to lowercase due to the case difference in your value and your url
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/"+selectedValue+".html";
});
```

But if its in a `form` tag the use this instead

```
$('form').submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    selectedValue = $('select').val().toLowerCase(); //I converted it to lowercase due to the case difference in your value and your url
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/"+selectedValue+".html";
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joon You are welcome, I would also appreciate if you can upvote my answer please :)